# Server.MapPath to go two folder back from root

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Here is how I do it:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\~\~\Content\")
```

HI know that '.' is for the root of the project, but how to go a few folders back?

Comment: Think you want `@"..\..\..\Content\"`

Comment: @danRhul I get error "You cant use leading ..."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you really need the grandparent path, you can get it from the root path using [`Path.GetDirectoryName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx):

```
string root = Server.MapPath("~");
string parent = Path.GetDirectoryName(root);
string grandParent = Path.GetDirectoryName(parent);
```

But your web app very likely won't have permission to read or write there - I'm not sure what you're going to do with it.

Comment: root, parent and grandParent all return the same path. Why?

Comment: Really? I don't have an ASP.NET site to hand to test this in, but I tried an example in LinqPad starting from c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp and it worked OK. I'd be surprised if Path was set up to restrict you - after all it's just processing a string. So I haven't tested this in the exact environment but I am surprised if it doesn't just work. (I realise now my code is assuming root doesn't have a trailing slash - you might need another Path.GetDirectoryName to get rid of that if one exists.)

Answer (score 4):

Start with the root of your site with `~` and specify the full path: `~/Archive/Content`.

**You can't go back above site root** because of security restrictions, see also [this article](http://forums.iis.net/t/1164147.aspx) from other solutions.

> IIS purposefully prevents serving up content directly that is outside of the site path. However, you can create a virtual directory in IIS and have ISAPI Rewrite point to that. For example, create a virtual directory called /staticfiles that points to c:\test\data\static-files. As far as IIS is concerned, that's directly off of the root of the site in a folder called /staticfiles.

Comment: How does this help me? It doesn't go back.

Comment: Go back where? Specify the path of **Content** starting from web site root.

Comment: The file in which I'm writing the Command isn't in the same project as the web site.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Parent.Parent.FullName**

```
  string grandParent  = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/")).Parent.Parent.FullName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using MapPath you are getting returned a physical path(\) from a virtual path(/).

Creating a DirectoryInfo object or using a Path utility method starting from your child app root won't necessarily give you what you expect unless your virtual parent and virtual grandparent have the same hierarchy as your physical directory structure.

My apps are not physically nested to match the Url depth.  This could also be the case if a virtual directory is involved.

Assuming a grandparent app is two virtual folders up this would get you the physical path...

```
    string physicalGrandparentPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/../../");
```

Using this would keep you safe from any virtual directory shuffle games going on in the IIS setup.

I used this to see how far I could go up. I did not get an HttpException until I tried to go above wwwroot.

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect !

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, you can still use the following:

```
string MyFolderName = Server.MapPath("~/AliasName/");
```

Add a **Virtual Directory** to your application. Here's how:

- In Visual Studio under your root folder right click:
- Add > ***New Virtual Directory***
- Alias name: ***AliasName***
- Folder: click on > ***Browse*...**
- Navigate to the folder you need and done.

That's it, now you have access!