# Set razor view path to a external folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

Currently we use plugins with razorgenerator. This works ok, but when the view needs to be editted it needs to be compiled every time. This makes us less productive then wanted. I was working on a custom razor viewengine to solve this. To get it working I need to set the view for the area's to a local directory.

I tried

```
public class PluginRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public PluginRazorViewEngine()
    {
       var x = this.AreaViewLocationFormats.ToList();
        x.Insert(0, "C:/XXXXX/Areas/Module/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
        this.AreaViewLocationFormats = x.ToArray();
     }
 }
```

Though this gives the error:

```
   The relative virtual path 'C:/XXXXX/Areas/Module/Views/Items/Index.cshtml' is not allowed here.
```

Is it possible to set the viewpath outside of the project?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find exactly where that error is thrown but I believe you cannot set a path outside of the application the way you are trying to. The `RazorViewEngine` inherits from [`BuildManagerViewEngine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.buildmanagerviewengine%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which in turn inherits from [`VirtualPathProviderViewEngine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.virtualpathproviderviewengine%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). The `VirtualPathProviderViewEngine` uses the [`VirtualPathProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the host environment.
Thus, it seems you cannot use a direct path and are required to pass in a Virtual path or you could rewrite the underlying layers yourself by directly inheriting from [`IViewEngine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iviewengine%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which is what `VirtualPathProviderViewEngine` inherits from (see image below).

I might be mistaken but I also believe this is enforcing the same principle as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9725664/1453651) that you cannot deliver content from outside the site path.

Have you tried using a relative path to see if that gets mapped correctly. A relative path dependent on the [application's root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275791/1453651)?

Looking through the source of [`VirtualPathProviderViewEngine`](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/27e9a28d5b7ef79650ccfc6e04dd876a65cd72c1#src/System.Web.Mvc/VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.cs) you will also notice that the `FileExists` method of the `VirtualPathProvider` class is used extensively to find the requested razor file.

[image: FileExists method of VirtualPathProviderViewEngine]

[image: Inheritance hierarchy of RazorViewEngine]

Source of inheritance diagram: http://theshravan.net/blog/configure-the-views-search-locations-in-asp-net-mvc/