# Load excel file and write

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel file in `"D:\SOURCE\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME\File\MyExcelFile.xlsx"`

So, i can get this path by

`"D:\\SOURCE\\PROJECTNAME\\PROJECTNAME\\File\\MyExcelFile.xlsx"`

but i want to use something like `"~\\File\\MyExcelFile.xlsx"`

I'm newbie with C#, can anyone help?

Comment: which application template r u using `WinForm`, `Asp.Net`, `Asp.Net MVC` or any else?

Comment: i'm using `Asp.Net`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Server.MapPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
Server.MapPath("File/Excel.xlsx")
```

Comment: It's `D:\SOURCE\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME\WebService\File\MyFile.xlsx`

Comment: if this code works then mark it as an answer or check for alternate suggestions

Comment: i need `D:\SOURCE\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME\File\MyFile.xlsx`
but your answer return `D:\SOURCE\PROJECTNAME\PROJECTNAME\WebService\File\MyFile.xlsx`
But i can use this and substring, thank you so much

Comment: dont use substring and it's not standard, check this instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725584/server-mappath-to-go-two-folder-back-from-root

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "File/MyExcelFile.xlsx")` if your files are being copied to `Bin` folder.